# Problem creating new command in `array` ensemble

Tags: tcl

I want to create a convenience command `array values arrayName` as a "flip side" to the "array names" command.

It's straightforward to create a simple proc:

```
proc array_values {arrayName} {
    upvar 1 $arrayName ary
    set values {}
    foreach {name value} [array get ary] {lappend values $value}
    return $values
}

array set a {foo bar baz qux}
puts [array_values a]           ;# => bar qux
```

However, I'm having difficulty creating a command in the `::tcl::array` namespace:

- first some homework:

  1. is `array` a namespace ensemble? Yes.

     ```
     % namespace ensemble exists array
     1
     ```
  2. what is the namespace?

     ```
     % namespace ensemble configure array -namespace
     ::tcl::array
     ```
  3. what are the subcommands?

     ```
     % namespace ensemble configure array -subcommands
     % namespace ensemble configure array -map
     anymore ::tcl::array::anymore donesearch ::tcl::array::donesearch exists ::tcl::array::exists get ::tcl::array::get names ::tcl::array::names nextelement ::tcl::array::nextelement set ::tcl::array::set size ::tcl::array::size startsearch ::tcl::array::startsearch statistics ::tcl::array::statistics unset ::tcl::array::unset
     ```

OK, all good so var. Let's add that `array_values` proc into the namespace

```
% namespace eval ::tcl::array {
    proc values {arrayName} {
        upvar 1 $arrayName ary
        set values {}
        foreach {name value} [array get ary] {lappend values $value}
        return $values
    }
}
% array set a {foo bar baz qux}
% puts [::tcl::array::values a]
```

```
can't set "values": variable is array
```

Where is this error coming from? I tried renaming the "values" variable in the proc to other names, but it still emits the "variable is array" error.

---

a note: I can add the first proc to the ensemble:

```
% namespace ensemble config array -map [list values ::array_values {*}[namespace ensemble config array -map]]
% array values a
bar qux
```

But what is wrong with my `::tcl::array::values` proc?

Comment: As a follow-up on Schelte's answer: Also `foreach` would have to be qualified, since ::tcl::array::foreach is about to become available (in 8.7, if I am right)? See also my complementary answer.

Comment: Just to close this loop, TP 421 implements `array for` -- https://core.tcl.tk/tcl/info/7c614b93309da90a

Comment: Correct, I was confused by the progenitor discussion on the corresponding bounty: https://github.com/flightaware/Tcl-bounties/issues/27

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `set values {}` command executes in the ::tcl::array namespace, so it runs the ::tcl::array::set command. In other words, it does the equivalent of `array set values {}`. So it makes values an array with no members. Then the `lappend values $value` command fails because values is an array at that point.

The solution should be to use `::set values {}`

Or you can completely avoid the issue by using:

```
proc array_values {arrayName} {
    upvar 1 $arrayName ary
    return [lmap {name value} [get ary] {string cat $value}]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that, given that the presence of possibly conflicting ensemble commands is a moving target, patching an ensemble is likely to occur from everywhere, I have seen core developers keep extra ensemble commands outside the `::tcl::array::*` namespace:

```
proc arrayValues {arrayName} {
    upvar 1 $arrayName ary
    set values {}
    foreach {name value} [array get ary] {lappend values $value}
    return $values
}

# implant "arrayValues" into [array] ensemble as "values"
namespace ensemble configure ::array -map \
    [dict replace [namespace ensemble configure ::array -map] \
     values [namespace which arrayValues]]
```

This way, you don't have to worry about unintended resolution conflicts (whatever that means in Tcl, to begin with).

Comment: Just figured that you had that sorted out anyways (`::array_values`).

Answer (score 0):

For the curious, this is what I have ended up with:

$HOME/tcl/lib/monkeypatches/monkeypatches.tcl

```
# a set of useful additions to built-in ensembles

package provide monkeypatches 0.1

namespace eval ::monkeypatches {
    # https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/wrapping+commands
    proc append_subcommand {cmd subcmd procname} {
        set map [namespace ensemble configure $cmd -map]
        dict set map $subcmd [namespace which $procname]
        namespace ensemble configure $cmd -map $map
    }


    # array foreach
    # to be subsumed by https://core.tcl.tk/tips/doc/trunk/tip/421.md
    #
    # example:
    #   array set A {foo bar baz qux}
    #   array foreach {key val} A {puts "name=$key, value=$val"}
    #
    proc array_foreach {vars arrayName body} {
        if {[llength $vars] != 2} {
            error {array foreach: "vars" must be a 2 element list}
        }
        lassign $vars keyVar valueVar

        # Using the complicated `upvar 1 $arrayName $arrayName` so that any
        # error messages propagate up with the user's array name
        upvar 1 $arrayName $arrayName \
                $keyVar    key \
                $valueVar  value

        set sid [array startsearch $arrayName]
        # If the array is modified while a search is ongoing, the searchID will
        # be invalidated: wrap the commands that use $sid in a try block.
        try {
            while {[array anymore $arrayName $sid]} {
                set key [array nextelement $arrayName $sid]
                set value [set "${arrayName}($key)"]
                uplevel 1 $body
            }
            array donesearch $arrayName $sid
        } trap {TCL LOOKUP ARRAYSEARCH} {"" e} {
            return -options $e "detected attempt to modify the array while iterating"
        }
        return
    }
    append_subcommand ::array foreach array_foreach


    # array values arrayName
    # https://stackoverflow.com/q/53379995/7552
    #
    # example:
    #   array set x {foo bar baz qux}
    #   array get x             ;# => foo bar baz qux
    #   array names x           ;# => foo baz
    #   array values x          ;# => bar qux
    #
    proc array_values {arrayName} {
        upvar 1 $arrayName ary
        set values [list]
        array foreach {name value} ary {lappend values $value}
        return $values
    }
    append_subcommand ::array values array_values


    # info formalargs procName
    # https://core.tcl.tk/tips/doc/trunk/tip/65.md
    #
    # example:
    #   proc test {one {two 2} {three {3 4 5}} args} {return}
    #   info args test          ;# => one two three args
    #   info formalargs test    ;# => one {two 2} {three {3 4 5}} args
    #
    proc info_formalargs {procname} {
        # [info args] throws an error if $procname is not a procedure.
        return [lmap arg [info args $procname] {
            set has_d [info default $procname $arg value]
            if {$has_d} then {list $arg $value} else {set arg}
        }]
    }
    append_subcommand ::info formalargs info_formalargs
}
```

With its associated pkgIndex.tcl

And $HOME/.tclshrc

```
set lib_dir [file join $env(HOME) tcl lib]
if {$lib_dir ni $auto_path} {lappend auto_path $lib_dir}
unset lib_dir
package require monkeypatches
```