# `array nextelement` -- can't catch error when searchId has been invalidated

Tags: tcl

I've been [experimenting with namespace ensembles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53379995/7552) and I'm doing an exercise to implement `array foreach` (yes, I'm aware of [TIP 421](https://core.tcl.tk/tips/doc/trunk/tip/421.md)).

I'm using array startsearch/anymore/nextelement/donesearch. I'm now trying to catch the error that gets thrown when array elements are added or deleted while a search is in progress: I find that I cannot catch that error *in my code*, but I can catch it in an interactive session.

Here's an interactive session:

```
% array set Y {foo bar baz qux}
% set sid [array startsearch Y]
s-1-Y
% set key [array nextelement Y $sid]
foo
% set Y(hello) world
world
% try {
  set key [array nextelement Y $sid]
} trap {TCL LOOKUP} {msg e} {puts "$sid has been invalidated\n$e"}
s-1-Y has been invalidated
-code 1 -level 0 -errorstack {INNER {invokeStk1 ::tcl::array::nextelement Y s-1-Y}} -errorcode {TCL LOOKUP ARRAYSEARCH s-1-Y} -errorinfo {couldn't find search "s-1-Y"
    while executing
"array nextelement Y $sid"
    ("try" body line 1)} -errorline 1
%
```

All good. We can see the searchId is invalidated after I add an array element while an active search is ongoing: the  errorcode  starts with `{TCL LOOKUP ARRAYSEARCH}`

Now, I wrap this in a proc and arrange for it to be sourced when I start an interactive tclsh (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53385353/7552) for the details). Here's the body for my `array foreach` proc:

```
% info body ::monkeypatches::array_foreach

    if {[llength $vars] != 2} {
        error {array foreach: "vars" must be a 2 element list}
    }
    lassign $vars keyVar valueVar

    # Using the complicated `upvar 1 $arrayName $arrayName` so that any
    # error messages propagate up with the user's array name
    upvar 1 $arrayName $arrayName  $keyVar    key  $valueVar  value

    set sid [array startsearch $arrayName]
    while {[array anymore $arrayName $sid]} {
        # This doesn't seem to be able to catch the error when the user
        # tries to modify the array during a search. Hmm.
        try {
            set key [array nextelement $arrayName $sid]
        } trap {TCL LOOKUP ARRAYSEARCH} {"" e} {
            return -options $e "detected attempt to modify the array while iterating"
        }
        set value [set "${arrayName}($key)"]
        uplevel 1 $body
    }
    array donesearch $arrayName $sid
    return
```

When I reproduce the steps to catch the error, I find that my `try` does not catch the error:

```
% array set Y {foo bar baz qux}
% array foreach {key val} Y {set Y(hello) world}
couldn't find search "s-1-Y"
```

Replacing the specific `trap` clause with a generic `on error` does not help. Neither does using `catch` instead of `try`.

I don't understand why this proc cannot catch the error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the error trace, you see that the error isn't coming from where you expect. (I created the procedure as `array_foreach` for the purposes of this test.)

```
% array_foreach {x y} tcl_platform {set tcl_platform(foo) bar;puts $x->$y}
osVersion->16.7.0
couldn't find search "s-1-tcl_platform"
% set errorInfo
couldn't find search "s-1-tcl_platform"
    while executing
"array anymore $arrayName $sid"
    (procedure "array_foreach" line 12)
    invoked from within
"array_foreach {x y} tcl_platform {set tcl_platform(foo) bar;puts $x->$y}"
```

You've put the trap on `array nextelement`, but not on `array anymore` which is what actually detects the problem (and throws).

I guess that you'd be better off changing the loop to this:

```
while true {
    try {
        if {![array anymore $arrayName $sid]} {
            break
        }
        set key [array nextelement $arrayName $sid]
        set value [set ${arrayName}($key)]
    } trap {TCL LOOKUP ARRAYSEARCH} {"" e} {
        return -options $e "detected attempt to modify the array while iterating"
    }
    uplevel 1 $body
}
```

Comment: D'oh. Thanks Donal.